# WINAPI - I would like to have the message pump ongoing in a separate thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

In the Windows API, making a window requires a message pump to keep the window running and updated. Now, writing a message pump consists of a while loop, which dominates the entire program, not allowing other things to be executed, which is a big problem.

Consider my code, which is a header file that I called `CFrame.h` (because inside I made a class called `CFrame` which is meant to mimick `JFrame` in Java). In other words, I want it to be possible to create multiple instances of `CFrame` so that multiple windows show up and the message loop will not stop the windows after the first one from being created.

I made a new thread for the function `ThreadExecution()`, for some reason the program just terminates, why?

```
#define UNICODE

#include <windows.h>

const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Window Class";
static int nWindows = 0; // Number of ongoing windows 

class Size { // Size of the window
private:
    int width;
    int height;
    public:
    Size(int width, int height) :width(width), height(height) {}
    int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }
    int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
};

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_DESTROY: nWindows--; break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

void RegisterDetails(HINSTANCE hInstance) { // Registers WNDCLASS
    WNDCLASS wc = {};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    RegisterClass(&wc);
}

void startMessageLoop() { // This is the message loop which must be in a    separate thread
    MSG msg;
    while (nWindows) {
        GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

HWND CreateAWindow(LPCWSTR title, Size size, HINSTANCE hInstance) {
    if (nWindows == 0) { // The WNDCLASS only needs to be registered once
        RegisterDetails(hInstance);
    }
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, CLASS_NAME, title, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,     CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, size.getWidth(), size.getHeight(), NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, 5);
    return hwnd;
}


void ThreadExecution(HWND hwnd, LPCWSTR title, Size size, HINSTANCE hInstance) {
    hwnd = CreateAWindow(title, size, hInstance);
    nWindows++;
    if (nWindows == 1) // If only one window has been created, the message loop will be called
    {
        startMessageLoop();
    }
}

class CFrame {

private:
    HINSTANCE hInstance;
    Size size;
    HWND hwnd;

public:
    CFrame() { 
    }

    CFrame(LPCWSTR title, Size size, HINSTANCE hInstance) :size(size), hInstance(hInstance) 
    { 
        std::thread t1(ThreadExecution, hwnd, title, size, hInstance);
        t1.detach();
    }
};
```

Comment: maybe move your work to another thread instead of the message loop?

Comment: and what is your question here?

Comment: @appleapple: That's fairly clear. The message pump shown does not return, and therefore the `CFrame` ctor does not return either, which explains why you can't create two `CFrame` objects on the same thread.

Comment: @MSalters well, I just want @ MarkoCrush add a little description to what is wrong

Comment: @appleapple Excuse me for that, the question has been updated with a clearer description of the issue.

Comment: @MarkoCrush By the way, if you only want multiple window, just call `CreateWindow` multiple times will be fine.

Comment: Yeah but you can't when the message loop dominates the entire program which is my problem. I want it to be possible to dynamically create new windows without the message loop blocking it.

Comment: You are going about this totally the wrong way. Learn how the system is meant to work. Don't fight it.

Comment: Why do you insist, that you need to spread this across threads? Games usually run all everything on a single thread, with a message loop based on `PeekMessage`, that depletes the message queue, and then renders a frame, and starts over. Why can't you do that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it follows the pattern: *"<Wrong assumption> - How do I work around this issue?"* This is not generally useful.

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly OK to have a message pump on a non-`main` thread. However, the message pump must be on the thread that created the window. In your case, that means that `CreateAWindow` and `startMessageLoop` must be called from the same thread.

Comment: Do I then use CreateThread two times, one for CreateAWindow and one for startMessageLoop?

Comment: @MarkoCrush: No, that is precisely **the opposite** of what I said. Use the **same** thread. Also, use `std::thread` since you're writing C++ code, and call `.detach` on that thread. The WINAPI `CreateThread` is the OS interface, and does not know whether you're going to run FORTRAN, Java or C++ code on that thread, so it generally needs to be wrapped.

Comment: Sorry about that, you meant for me to make a thread that will pack the functions CreateAWindow and startMessageLoop. I will try it with the std::thread. Thanks.

Comment: std::thread t1(CreateAWindow);
std::thread t1(startMessageLoop);
t1.detach();     This clearly can't work, how would I put both inside t1?

Comment: `std::thread([]{new CFrame}).detach()` would work. Don't forget to call `delete this` in `CFrame::~CFrame`, which you must call in response to `WM_CLOSE`. And `WM_CLOSE` is of course handled by the message pump inside that thread.

Comment: Do I call it inside the constructor and if so do I do it all the way at the top? There also seems to be a syntax error: "expected ;".

Comment: @MarkoCrush: You're probably a novice to C++. `new CFrame` actually calls the constructor, so calling if _from_ the constructor would create a stack overflow (or you run out of threads, whatever comes first). And yes, to turn that `...detach()` call into a stand-alone statement you need to add a `;`.

Comment: I just updated my code and question, for some reason putting those two functions into a separate thread causes the program to terminate.

Comment: And yes I have only been programming in C++ for two months, I have been otherwise programming in Java for a year. I still know most of the concepts though.

Comment: @MarkoCrush: Well, the updated code has other issues precisely because C++ isn't Java. C++ doesn't have Garbage Collection and normal variables are objects, not references to objects. Therefore your `hwnd`  function argument is not a reference to `CFrame::hwnd`. But we're digressing - you'll need to debug your program. My guess is that your program terminates simply because `CFrame` now returns, and therefore `main`. Not a threading issue, you simply run out of things to do.

Answer (score 3):

> Now, writing a message pump consists of a while loop, which dominates the entire program, not allowing other things to be executed

A *traditional* message loop might work that way, but it is certainly possible to write a message loop that can do other things in between messages.  And who says that you can't use messages themselves to do things.  You might have a loop that blocks the calling thread, but you control what that loop actually does on each iteration, so it can do things on behalf of its calling thread.  It is not required to *only* process messages.

> In other words, I want it to be possible to create multiple instances of CFrame so that multiple windows show up and the message loop will not stop the windows after the first one from being created.

Any kind of message loop can handle multiple windows in the same thread just fine.

> I made a new thread for the function `ThreadExecution()`, for some reason the program just terminates, why?

Because your window management is completely wrong. You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how windows and threads work together.  You don't create a separate thread for each window (though you technically can, but it is wasteful to do so).  You create one thread (or just use your main thread) to create multiple windows, and then use a single message loop to service them.

Try something more like this:

```
#ifndef CFrameH
#define CFrameH

#include <windows.h>

class Size { // Size of the window
private:
    int width;
    int height;
public:
    Size(int width, int height);

    int getWidth() const;
    int getHeight() const;
};

class CFrame {
private:
    HINSTANCE hInstance;
    Size size;
    HWND hwnd;

    virtual LRESULT WndProc(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

    static void RegisterDetails(HINSTANCE);
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

public:
    CFrame(LPCWSTR title, Size size, HINSTANCE hInstance);
    ~CFrame();
};

#endif
```

CFrame.cpp

```
#include "CFrame.h"

static LPCWSTR CLASS_NAME = L"Window Class";

Size::Size(int width, int height)
    : width(width), height(height)
{
}

int Size::getWidth() const {
    return width;
}

int Size::getHeight() const {
    return height;
}

CFrame::CFrame(LPCWSTR title, Size size, HINSTANCE hInstance)
    : size(size), hInstance(hInstance) 
{ 
    RegisterDetails(hInstance);

    hwnd = CreateWindowExW(0, CLASS_NAME, title, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, size.getWidth(), size.getHeight(), NULL, NULL, hInstance, this);
    if (hwnd) {
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    }
}

CFrame::~CFrame()
{ 
    if (hwnd)
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
}

void CFrame::RegisterDetails(HINSTANCE hInstance) { // Registers WNDCLASS
    WNDCLASSW wc = {};
    BOOL bRegistered = GetClassInfoW(hInstance, CLASS_NAME, &wc);
    if ((!bRegisterd) || (wc.lpfnWndProc != &WindowProc)) {
        if (bRegistered) {
          UnregisterClassW(CLASS_NAME, hInstance);
        }
        wc.lpfnWndProc = &WindowProc;
        wc.hInstance = hInstance;
        wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
        RegisterClassW(&wc);
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK CFrame::WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    CFrame *pThis;

    if (uMsg == WM_CREATE) {
        pThis = (CFrame*) ((CREATESTRUCT*)lParam)->lpCreateParams;
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR) pThis);
    } else {
        pThis = (CFrame*) GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA);
    }

    if (pThis)
        return pThis->WndProc(uMsg, wParam, lParam);

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}        

LRESULT CFrame::WndProc(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_NCDESTROY) {
        hwnd = NULL;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Then you can do things like this in a thread:

```
void ThreadExecution(HINSTANCE hInstance) {
    CFrame frame1(L"frame1", Size(10, 10), hInstance);
    CFrame frame2(L"frame2", Size(20, 20), hInstance);

    MSG msg;
    while (...) {
        if (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
}
```

```
void ThreadExecution(HINSTANCE hInstance) {
    CFrame frame1(L"frame1", Size(10, 10), hInstance);
    CFrame frame2(L"frame2", Size(20, 20), hInstance);

    MSG msg;
    while (...) {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else {
            // do something else
        }
    }
}
```

```
void ThreadExecution(HINSTANCE hInstance) {
    CFrame frame1(L"frame1", Size(10, 10), hInstance);
    CFrame frame2(L"frame2", Size(20, 20), hInstance);

    // array of event/IO objects that are signaled
    // when things needs to be done...
    HANDLE hObjects[...];
    DWORD dwNumObjects = ...;
    ...

    MSG msg;
    while (...) {
        DWORD dwRet = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(dwNumObjects, hObjects, FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT);
        if ((dwRet >= WAIT_OBJECT_0) && (dwRet < (WAIT_OBJECT_0+dwNumObjects))) {
            dwRet -= WAIT_OBJECT_0;
            // do something with hObjects[dwRet] ...
        }
        else if (dwRet == (WAIT_OBJECT_0+dwNumObjects)) {
            while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

And so on...

Answer (score 1):

You can move

- create window
- run message loop

into a method, and use thread to execute this method

---

- std::thread seems not work, you need `CreateThread` instead
- Of course, you can encapsulate this in class.

---

As you are create game API, maybe you can use `PeekMessage`(non-block) and do your own timer or something?

Comment: So you suggest that I create a function that will call those two functions, and that function will be called by a thread?

Comment: @MarkoCrush yes, and it is more easy to implement (I think)

Comment: I edited my code and question, for some reason the program just terminates when I do as you said.

Comment: @MarkoCrush I am not very sure that one can create window on different thread other than main, maybe change your "get create window command" to another thread and use post/send message and drive the loop?

Comment: Oh windows are welcome to remain in the main thread, I am talking about the message loop which should be in a different thread as it interferes with the program as a whole.

Comment: @MarkoCrush what about make your "whole program" (except window/message things) in another thread

Comment: I'm working on creating a game API, now imagine future users of my API had to always make a thread when calling wWinMain?

Comment: @MarkoCrush answer edited, maybe `PeekMessage` is what you need?

Comment: @MarkoCrush I tested `std::thread` version with very simple code, and it still terminate on `CreateWindowEx`.

Comment: I like that one! A timer! Didn't think of it! Thanks!

Comment: @MarkoCrush I'll still recommend use thread though. CreateThread works find.

Comment: @MarkoCrush you may still need a thread to work on window messages to keep you concentrate on your API

Comment: HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadExecution, NULL, NULL, 0);

Comment: @MarkoCrush Can you run my example in another(below) answer without tremination?

Answer (score 1):

std::thread seems not work, you can use `CreateThread` instead

---

(Simple) Sample Code

```
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>

const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Window Class";

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

DWORD WINAPI CreateWindowAndRunUseMesageLoop(LPVOID* id){
    WCHAR className[] = L"XCLASSSSS";
    WCHAR title[] = L"XTITLE";
    title[0] = *(WCHAR*)id;
    className[0] = *(WCHAR*)id;
    WNDCLASS wc = {};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wc.lpszClassName = className;
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    auto hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, className, title, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT
        , 300, 300, NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    HANDLE handle[2];
    WCHAR i = L'0';
    handle[0] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)CreateWindowAndRunUseMesageLoop, &i, 0, NULL);
    WCHAR j = L'1';
    handle[1] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)CreateWindowAndRunUseMesageLoop, &j, 0, NULL);
    WaitForMultipleObjects(2, handle, TRUE, INFINITE);
}
```

Comment: `std::thread` is fine. But this code will be a disaster. Running UI away from the UI thread generally ends in pain. Don't do it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The code is fine as far as having two distinct UI threads. There is no immediate issue here, like a window hierarchy straddling thread boundaries. A statement like `ShowWindow(hwnd, 5);`, on the other hand, does worry me. It's a pretty safe guess, that the author never felt the need to read the documentation.

Comment: @IInspectable Why? I put in the literal 5 so that I don't need to put in nCmdShow?

Comment: @MarkoCrush: There are named constants, so that I don't have to open my web browser, navigate to the documentation, and work out, what `5` is supposed do.

Comment: @IInspectable the code that I'm working on will happen in the background of making a window, I put five there as I didn't want nCmdShow. I would amazed if you're making a great deal out using five instead of a "named constant", which by the way is in fact a name alias.

Comment: @MarkoCrush: That didn't make much sense. Regardless, which version would you hope to see, if you read someone else's code: `ShowWindow(hWnd, 5);` or `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);`. I have an undisputed favorite here. If you don't, you're in for a bit of fun, once you join your first team.

Comment: I just told you that nobody will read that part of the code, it's "in the background of making windows". In other words I only want the class CFrame to be accessed and the rest will be taken care of internally.

Comment: @MarkoCrush: *"nobody will read that part of the code"* - Posting it on a web site, that's visited literally by millions is a great way, to go about accomplishing that goal. It seems like you are generally unaware of the effects of your actions.

Comment: I'm working on making an API genius, so nobody will.