# C++ making a separate thread in the Windows API, program terminates?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

For some reason using the thread and detaching it trying to run the message   loop for the window in a separate thread the program just terminates?

If you look down at the CFrame constructor, I made a thread t1 passing in the startMessageLoop function and then detached the thread so that the while loop will not dominate the whole program, but instead the program just terminates? This even happens in when the entry point is int main() where you have to use system("PAUSE") to prevent the program from terminating.

```
#define UNICODE

#include <windows.h>
#include <thread>

const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Window Class";
static int nWindows = 0; // Number of ongoing windows 

class Size { // Size of the window
  private:
    int width;
    int height;
  public:
     Size() {}
     Size(int width, int height) :width(width), height(height) {}
  int getWidth() {
     return width;
  }
  int getHeight() {
     return height;
  }
};

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_DESTROY: nWindows--; break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}  

void RegisterDetails(HINSTANCE hInstance) { // Registers WNDCLASS
    WNDCLASS wc = {};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    RegisterClass(&wc);
}

void startMessageLoop() { // This is the message loop which must be in a   separate thread
    MSG msg;
    while (nWindows) { 
        GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

HWND CreateAWindow(LPCWSTR title, Size size, HINSTANCE hInstance) {
    if (nWindows == 0) { // The WNDCLASS only needs to be registered once
        RegisterDetails(hInstance);
    }
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, CLASS_NAME, title, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, size.getWidth(), size.getHeight(), NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, 5);
    return hwnd;
}


class CFrame {

private:
    HINSTANCE hInstance;
    Size size;
    HWND hwnd;

public:
    CFrame() { 
}

CFrame(LPCWSTR title, Size size, HINSTANCE hInstance) :size(size), hInstance(hInstance) 
    { 
        hwnd = CreateAWindow(title, size, hInstance);
        nWindows++;
        if (nWindows == 1) {
            std::thread t1(startMessageLoop);
            t1.detach();
        }
    }
};

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    CFrame frame1 = CFrame{ L"Window1", Size{ 800, 600 }, hInstance };

}
```

Comment: It looks like you are repeating the same question. What are you trying to do here? Do you realize that you can have one process, one thread, and multiple windows and owned windows? Creating multiple GUI threads is not advisable.

Comment: Have you tried making your `nWindows` variable an `atomic<int>`? Even if you set it to `1` from main thread, other thread may not read the same value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WINAPI - I would like to have the message pump ongoing in a separate thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39895561/winapi-i-would-like-to-have-the-message-pump-ongoing-in-a-separate-thread)

Comment: *"so that the while loop will not dominate the whole program"* - The duplicate question has an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39909192/1889329) that already explains, that this assumption is wrong. And provides alternatives that work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A windows message queue is tied to a thread. Messages posted to a window go to the message queue of the thread associated with that window. If you create a window on one thread, that is the thread whose message queue will get messages for that window and is the one that needs a message loop to dispatch messages to the window's windows procedure.

Your main creates a window and also starts a new thread that runs a message loop on the second thread's message queue. Since nothing is ever put in that second message queue, your second thread never does anything.

Your main, however, immediately exits. This terminates your main thread and along with it your entire program.

Answer (score 2):

Your process exits because your main thread (wWinMain) exits, other threads are not considered in this regard. You should make wWinMain wait until the other threads are running, e.g. by calling t1.join (since it is a local variable in CFrame's constructor, you will have to pass a reference to it).

Another problem with your code is the Race Condition connected to the global variable nWindows, you should protect it with a CriticalSection or a Mutex, or use InterlockedIncrease/Decrease. (But this is not the cause of that your program exits immediatelly.)

And you have to call CreateAWindow from startMessageLoop to receive the messages from Windows on thread t1.

I hope that this is some kind of experimenting/learning project because employing more UI threads is not recommended (it does not make the program more responsive by decreasing latency and it does not enforce modularity like a process boundary).